# NFS boot for BBB with Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: linux, networking, boot, nfs

I recently updated my system to Ubuntu 18.04.5 to 22.04 (fresh installation). On the old system I had a Yocto project for my BBB using TFTP and NFS to boot from my machine. Everything worked fine, but since the update I just cannot get NFS up and booting, while TFPT works fine. I scanned the internet for days and tried so many things, but still no booting of my BBB from the NFS server. After loading the Kernel it gets stuck. Here is my boot log from the BBB:

```
U-Boot SPL 2021.01-g15769936a5 (Dec 06 2021 - 21:28:58 +0000)
Trying to boot from MMC1


U-Boot 2021.01-g15769936a5 (Dec 06 2021 - 21:28:58 +0000)

CPU  : AM335X-GP rev 2.1
Model: TI AM335x BeagleBone Black
DRAM:  512 MiB
WDT:   Started with servicing (60s timeout)
NAND:  0 MiB
MMC:   OMAP SD/MMC: 0, OMAP SD/MMC: 1
Loading Environment from FAT... OK
Net:   eth2: ethernet@4a100000, eth3: usb_ether
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0 
link up on port 0, speed 100, full duplex
Using ethernet@4a100000 device
TFTP from server 192.168.5.1; our IP address is 192.168.5.10
Filename 'zImage'.
Load address: 0x81000000
Loading: #################################################################
     #################################################################
     #################################################################
     #################################################################
     #################################################################
     #############
     752.9 KiB/s
done
Bytes transferred = 4956672 (4ba200 hex)
link up on port 0, speed 100, full duplex
Using ethernet@4a100000 device
TFTP from server 192.168.5.1; our IP address is 192.168.5.10
Filename 'am335x-boneblack-rootbot.dtb'.
Load address: 0x82000000
Loading: #######
     3.1 MiB/s
done
Bytes transferred = 93887 (16ebf hex)
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 82000000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x82000000
   Loading Device Tree to 8ffe6000, end 8ffffebe ... OK

Starting kernel ...

[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.10.65-gdcc6bedb2c (oe-user@oe-host) (arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc (GCC) 9.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.34.0.20200220) #1 PREEMPT Fri Dec 3 15:28:30 UTC 2021
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [413fc082] revision 2 (ARMv7), cr=10c5387d
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache
[    0.000000] OF: fdt: Machine model: TI AM335x BeagleBone Black
[    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writeback
[    0.000000] efi: UEFI not found.
[    0.000000] cma: Reserved 48 MiB at 0x9c800000
[    0.000000] Zone ranges:
[    0.000000]   Normal   [mem 0x0000000080000000-0x000000009fefffff]
[    0.000000]   HighMem  empty
[    0.000000] Movable zone start for each node
[    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000080000000-0x000000009fefffff]
[    0.000000] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000080000000-0x000000009fefffff]
[    0.000000] CPU: All CPU(s) started in SVC mode.
[    0.000000] AM335X ES2.1 (sgx neon)
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 129666
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: rw root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=192.168.5.1:/opt/nfs ip=192.168.5.10 console=ttyO0,115200n8
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:off, heap free:off
[    0.000000] Memory: 452328K/523264K available (10240K kernel code, 692K rwdata, 3344K rodata, 1024K init, 282K bss, 21784K reserved, 49152K cma-reserved, 0K highmem)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=1, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] rcu: Preemptible hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000] rcu:     RCU event tracing is enabled.
[    0.000000]  Trampoline variant of Tasks RCU enabled.
[    0.000000] rcu: RCU calculated value of scheduler-enlistment delay is 10 jiffies.
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS: 16, nr_irqs: 16, preallocated irqs: 16
[    0.000000] IRQ: Found an INTC at 0x(ptrval) (revision 5.0) with 128 interrupts
[    0.000000] random: get_random_bytes called from start_kernel+0x30c/0x4c8 with crng_init=0
[    0.000000] TI gptimer clocksource: always-on /ocp/interconnect@44c00000/segment@200000/target-module@31000
[    0.000010] sched_clock: 32 bits at 24MHz, resolution 41ns, wraps every 89478484971ns
[    0.000027] clocksource: dmtimer: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 79635851949 ns
[    0.000341] TI gptimer clockevent: 24000000 Hz at /ocp/interconnect@48000000/segment@0/target-module@40000
[    0.001311] Console: colour dummy device 80x30
[    0.001350] WARNING: Your 'console=ttyO0' has been replaced by 'ttyS0'
[    0.001357] This ensures that you still see kernel messages. Please
[    0.001363] update your kernel commandline.
[    0.001415] Calibrating delay loop... 996.14 BogoMIPS (lpj=4980736)
[    0.090407] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.090563] Mount-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes, linear)
[    0.090577] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes, linear)
[    0.091408] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
[    0.091480] CPU0: Spectre v2: using BPIALL workaround
[    0.092291] Setting up static identity map for 0x80100000 - 0x80100060
[    0.092426] rcu: Hierarchical SRCU implementation.
[    0.092513] EFI services will not be available.
[    0.092867] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.103912] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 3 part 30 variant c rev 3
[    0.104157] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns
[    0.104180] futex hash table entries: 256 (order: -1, 3072 bytes, linear)
[    0.107573] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.108487] DMI not present or invalid.
[    0.108921] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.111120] DMA: preallocated 256 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
[    0.128713] l3-aon-clkctrl:0000:0: failed to disable
[    0.129895] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'fair_share'
[    0.129908] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'bang_bang'
[    0.129921] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'step_wise'
[    0.129928] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'user_space'
[    0.130275] cpuidle: using governor ladder
[    0.130313] cpuidle: using governor menu
[    1.157033] No ATAGs?
[    1.157062] hw-breakpoint: debug architecture 0x4 unsupported.
[    1.181241] iommu: Default domain type: Translated 
[    1.183363] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    1.183821] mc: Linux media interface: v0.10
[    1.183873] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    1.183976] pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
[    1.183985] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
[    1.184007] PTP clock support registered
[    1.184066] EDAC MC: Ver: 3.0.0
[    1.185230] Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Initialized.
[    1.186505] clocksource: Switched to clocksource dmtimer
[    1.193711] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    1.193926] IP idents hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
[    1.194892] tcp_listen_portaddr_hash hash table entries: 512 (order: 0, 4096 bytes, linear)
[    1.194931] TCP established hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
[    1.194974] TCP bind hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
[    1.195013] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 4096 bind 4096)
[    1.195127] UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes, linear)
[    1.195148] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes, linear)
[    1.195288] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    1.195826] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    1.195841] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    1.195848] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    1.195855] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    1.195872] PCI: CLS 0 bytes, default 64
[    1.197160] hw perfevents: enabled with armv7_cortex_a8 PMU driver, 5 counters available
[    1.198370] Initialise system trusted keyrings
[    1.198729] workingset: timestamp_bits=14 max_order=17 bucket_order=3
[    1.202443] squashfs: version 4.0 (2009/01/31) Phillip Lougher
[    1.203224] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
[    1.203274] Key type id_resolver registered
[    1.203282] Key type id_legacy registered
[    1.203365] nfs4filelayout_init: NFSv4 File Layout Driver Registering...
[    1.203377] nfs4flexfilelayout_init: NFSv4 Flexfile Layout Driver Registering...
[    1.203412] ntfs: driver 2.1.32 [Flags: R/O].
[    1.204002] Key type asymmetric registered
[    1.204022] Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered
[    1.204070] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 243)
[    1.204082] io scheduler mq-deadline registered
[    1.204091] io scheduler kyber registered
[    1.558544] omap-mailbox 480c8000.mailbox: omap mailbox rev 0x400
[    1.632765] debugfs: Directory '49000000.dma' with parent 'dmaengine' already present!
[    1.632812] edma 49000000.dma: TI EDMA DMA engine driver
[    1.652632] pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: 142 pins, size 568
[    1.702226] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 10 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
[    1.706837] 44e09000.serial: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x44e09000 (irq = 20, base_baud = 3000000) is a 8250
[    2.368230] printk: console [ttyS0] enabled
[    2.374244] 48022000.serial: ttyS1 at MMIO 0x48022000 (irq = 26, base_baud = 3000000) is a 8250
[    2.385917] omap_rng 48310000.rng: Random Number Generator ver. 20
[    2.392253] random: fast init done
[    2.395884] random: crng init done
[    2.417103] brd: module loaded
[    2.426871] loop: module loaded
[    2.434415] libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
[    2.496534] davinci_mdio 4a101000.mdio: davinci mdio revision 1.6, bus freq 1000000
[    2.504241] libphy: 4a101000.mdio: probed
[    2.510742] davinci_mdio 4a101000.mdio: phy[0]: device 4a101000.mdio:00, driver SMSC LAN8710/LAN8720
[    2.520650] cpsw-switch 4a100000.switch: initialized cpsw ale version 1.4
[    2.527601] cpsw-switch 4a100000.switch: ALE Table size 1024
[    2.533402] cpsw-switch 4a100000.switch: cpts: overflow check period 500 (jiffies)
[    2.541089] cpsw-switch 4a100000.switch: CPTS: ref_clk_freq:250000000 calc_mult:2147483648 calc_shift:29 error:0 nsec/sec
[    2.552183] cpsw-switch 4a100000.switch: Detected MACID = e4:15:f6:f7:07:be
[    2.560055] cpsw-switch 4a100000.switch: initialized (regs 0x4a100000, pool size 256) hw_ver:0019010C 1.12 (0)
[    2.571238] i2c /dev entries driver
[    2.577413] cpuidle: enable-method property 'ti,am3352' found operations
[    2.584773] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    2.591040] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    2.596368] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
[    2.604789] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    2.612751] remoteproc remoteproc0: wkup_m3 is available
[    2.621365] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    2.627256] Segment Routing with IPv6
[    2.631016] sit: IPv6, IPv4 and MPLS over IPv4 tunneling driver
[    2.637742] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    2.642563] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    2.647592] omap_voltage_late_init: Voltage driver support not added
[    2.654611] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
[    2.671766] OMAP GPIO hardware version 0.1
[    2.707089] tps65217-pmic: Failed to locate of_node [id: -1]
[    2.718992] tps65217-bl: Failed to locate of_node [id: -1]
[    2.727311] tps65217 0-0024: TPS65217 ID 0xe version 1.2
[    2.733111] omap_i2c 44e0b000.i2c: bus 0 rev0.11 at 400 kHz
[    2.742060] omap_i2c 4819c000.i2c: bus 2 rev0.11 at 100 kHz
[    2.756252] omap_gpio 44e07000.gpio: Could not set line 6 debounce to 200000 microseconds (-22)
[    2.768202] sdhci-omap 48060000.mmc: Got CD GPIO
[    2.773151] sdhci-omap 48060000.mmc: supply vqmmc not found, using dummy regulator
[    2.856868] mmc0: SDHCI controller on 48060000.mmc [48060000.mmc] using External DMA
[    2.866038] cpsw-switch 4a100000.switch: starting ndev. mode: dual_mac
[    2.932507] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address aaaa
[    2.941266] mmcblk0: mmc0:aaaa SL32G 29.7 GiB 
[    2.948250]  mmcblk0: p1 p2
[    2.958235] SMSC LAN8710/LAN8720 4a101000.mdio:00: attached PHY driver [SMSC LAN8710/LAN8720] (mii_bus:phy_addr=4a101000.mdio:00, irq=POLL)
[    7.127371] cpsw-switch 4a100000.switch eth0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control off
[    7.136654] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[    7.166698] IP-Config: Guessing netmask 255.255.255.0
[    7.171785] IP-Config: Complete:
[    7.175036]      device=eth0, hwaddr=e4:15:f6:f7:07:be, ipaddr=192.168.5.10, mask=255.255.255.0, gw=255.255.255.255
[    7.185639]      host=192.168.5.10, domain=, nis-domain=(none)
[    7.191670]      bootserver=255.255.255.255, rootserver=192.168.5.1, rootpath=
[    7.192950] ALSA device list:
[    7.203397]   No soundcards found.
[  103.540846] VFS: Unable to mount root fs via NFS.
[  103.545779] devtmpfs: mounted
[  103.554404] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1024K
[  103.588598] Run /sbin/init as init process
[  103.594497] Run /etc/init as init process
[  103.599034] Run /bin/init as init process
[  103.603361] Run /bin/sh as init process
[  103.608831] Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel. See Linux Documentation/admin-guide/init.rst for guidance.
[  103.623124] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel. See Linux Documentation/admin-guide/init.rst for guidance. ]---
```

This is my /etc/defaults/nfs-kernel-server config

```
# Number of servers to start up
RPCNFSDCOUNT=8

# Runtime priority of server (see nice(1))
RPCNFSDPRIORITY=0

# Options for rpc.mountd.
# If you have a port-based firewall, you might want to set up
# a fixed port here using the --port option. For more information, 
# see rpc.mountd(8) or http://wiki.debian.org/SecuringNFS
# To disable NFSv4 on the server, specify '--no-nfs-version 4' here
RPCMOUNTDOPTS="--manage-gids"

# Do you want to start the svcgssd daemon? It is only required for Kerberos
# exports. Valid alternatives are "yes" and "no"; the default is "no".
NEED_SVCGSSD=""

# Options for rpc.svcgssd.
RPCSVCGSSDOPTS=""

RPCNFSDOPTS="--nfs-version 2,3,4 --debug --syslog"
```

And my /etc/defaults/tftp-hpa config (which works just fine)

```
# /etc/default/tftpd-hpa

TFTP_USERNAME="tftp"
TFTP_DIRECTORY="/opt/tftp/tftpboot"
TFTP_ADDRESS=":69"
TFTP_OPTIONS="--secure --create"
```

Finally my /etc/exports file:

```
# /etc/exports: the access control list for filesystems which may be exported
#       to NFS clients.  See exports(5).
#
# Example for NFSv2 and NFSv3:
# /srv/homes       hostname1(rw,sync,no_subtree_check) hostname2(ro,sync,no_subtree_check)
#
# Example for NFSv4:
# /srv/nfs4        gss/krb5i(rw,sync,fsid=0,crossmnt,no_subtree_check)
# /srv/nfs4/homes  gss/krb5i(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
#

/opt/nfs 192.168.5.1/24(rw,async,no_subtree_check)
```

My firewall is disabled (on intension) and the IP address is statically configured (in both u-boot on the BBB and the interface in my nfs server machine). I can mount the nfs locally and have full access. Ownership of the nfs folder is set to nobody:nogroup with full permission (777).

Some more info of the services from the server machine:

```
$ cat /proc/fs/nfs/exports 
# Version 1.1
# Path Client(Flags) # IPs
/opt/nfs    192.168.5.1/24(rw,root_squash,async,wdelay,no_subtree_check,uuid=be9ef652:a58c4750:bdf20f7e:72b03c73,sec=1)
```

A snippet from systemctl:

```
systemctl --type=service --state=running
...
  nfs-blkmap.service            loaded active running pNFS block layout mapping daemon
  nfs-idmapd.service            loaded active running NFSv4 ID-name mapping service
  nfs-mountd.service            loaded active running NFS Mount Daemon
...
  tftpd-hpa.service             loaded active running LSB: HPA's tftp server
...
```

I finally traced the boot process with wireshark and after the TFTP boot has finished I see some NFS packets. Unfortunately I am not familiar enought with the details of the NFS or MOUNT protocols to further analyse what they are saying but MOUNT seems to try to connect to the right address and path:
[image]

Again, the very same configuration worked perfectly fine with 18.04, maybe something has changed, or I oversaw something. Any of the researches I did pointed out another step I am missing, so I have no idea, whats wrong.
I run out of ideas... can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like usually posting here led me to new ideas:
Looking into wireshark trace the NFS packets say "V2 NULL Call". So I mounted the nfs on my localhost but specified the version also to be V2:

```
$ mount -t nfs -o vers=2 192.168.5.1:/opt/nfs /mnt/
mount.nfs: requested NFS version or transport protocol is not supported
```

Here we go: Seems that Ubuntu 18.04 still supported NFS version 2 but 22.04 does not anymore. Therefore the very same config and image that worked before was no longer supported!
I updated my bootargs env var in uboot from

```
bootargs=rw root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=192.168.5.1:/opt/nfs ip=192.168.5.10 console=ttyO0,115200n8
```

to

```
bootargs=rw root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=192.168.5.1:/opt/nfs,vers=4 ip=192.168.5.10 console=ttyO0,115200n8
```

and it worked.

I leave this post and my answer for all who are not aware of the changed supported NFS protocol version support.